# Typescript: Why am I able to allocate a string value to my declared (interface) number object parameter

Tags: typescript

I have declared an interface:

```
export interface DateArray {
    year    : number;
}
```

and I am declaring a new variable in my component like so:

```
private dateArray: DateArray = {
    year: null
};
```

and in my component I am assigning a value to dateArray.year like:

```
this.dateArray.year = this.megaData[0][3];
```

Now what I do not understand is that no matter what the value of `this.megaData[0][3]` is (string, number, array), it gets assigned to `this.dateArray.year` without any problem.

When I do:

```
 this.dateArray.year = "A"
```

I get an error "can't assign string to number", but when the value of `this.megaData[0][3]` is `"A"`, then I get no error, and the output of:

```
        this.dateArray.year = this.megaData[0][3];
        console.log("this.dateArray.year);
```

is just `A`

`this.megaData` is just defined as `<any>` for now, is this maybe the problem?

Comment: `this.megaData is just defined as <any> for now, is this maybe the problem?` <= Correct as `any` means it could also be or contain a number.

Comment: exactly ... declare this.megaData as number[[]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `this.megaData` is just defined as `<any>` for now, is this maybe the problem?

Correct as `any` means it could also be, or contain, a number (*the declared type of property `year`*) so the assignment will not generate a type mismatch error.

Comment: So TS will just go by previous declared values, and not re-check every value that  is assigns to a variable to see if it relates? Meaning, it just hands down the "type", and doesn't work it out new every time it hands over a value. Hmm, that is a very different way of looking at it then for me.

Comment: @AlfaBravo - correct, that would be run time checking which is not enforceable by the transpiler.

Comment: That is the whole idea of a static type system. Javascript can change a variable type on the fly but that is a major cause of runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks for the well meaning explanations.  :)